# Looking for a pdf viewer with an ability to specify search string on command line

Tags: linux, command-line, search, pdf-reader

I would like to be able to specify a search in similar manner to "less -p search_string". I need it to quickly preview changes in pdf's generated with LaTeX so it should be possibly lightweight. It must run on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of searching shows that, according to `man xpdf` you can send a command `findNext` using remote server mode.

Comment: Xpdf remote commands feature is indeed very interesting. Thank you for pointing me to it. However, there appears to be no command for directly specifing the search string on the command line.